# Ubuntu - Remove dir and ignore filetypes

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a cronjob for Ubuntu where:

- all empty dir's should be removed
- if the dir is not empty then it should be removed if the only filetypes are txt or csv files

Currently I have:

```
find /path -depth rmdir {} \; 2>dev/null
```

What do I need to delete the folders which only have txt or csv files?

I don't want to delete all txt or csv files, just those folders which do not contain other filetypes.

Additional example:
Dir1

- SubDir1

  - SubSubDir1

    - File.txt
    - File.csv
- SubDir2

  - SubSubDir2

    - File.xml

SubSubDir1 should be deleted. Since SubDir1 and Dir is now empty they should be deleted as well.
SubSubDir2 contains another filetype and should no be deleted.

Comment: Please make sure you have good backups before trying out any such script.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for your warning. Backups are already completed

Comment: Until you know what you are doing, discarding error messages is extremely ill-advised.

Comment: Can there be subdirectories within the directories which contain only csv and txt files?  What should happen in this case?

Comment: @tripleee Yes that is possible.

Comment: And the answer to "what should happen in this case" is ...?

Comment: @triplee
Example has been added to question.

Comment: The example case I'm still looking for is, can SubSubDir1 contain another subdirectory and what should happen in that case?  In other words, should directories with only csv and txt files but also with subdirectories be deleted or not?

Comment: @triplee no that's not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could list the number of files in a folder with something like:

```
find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -not -iname '*.csv' -a -not -iname '*.txt' | wc -l
```

If the folder is empty or the folder contains exclusively txt and csv files, it shall print 1.

And to list folders so that they don’t mess up each other if you erase the parents first:

```
find /path -depth -type d
```

All in all, you may be able to achieve what you want with:

```
while read d
do
  if [ $(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -not -iname '*.csv' -a -not -iname '*.txt' | wc -l) -eq 1 ]
  then
    rm -rf "$d"
  fi
done < <(find /path -depth -type d)
```

But I also advocate a check somewhere so your cron doesn’t wipe your storage without your consent.

Comment: Great solution. Thank you very much!